# Joomla can't get guest acl to work

Tags: joomla, acl

I've set up ACL according to the joomla docs: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

I created a joomla guest group, parent is public, I ammended the options so that the guest group is guest etc.

I set the topmenu module to show for guest which I think should show for anyone visiting the site but I can seen nothing.

Help!!

thanks

Comment: A weird quirk I've noticed is that the group won't update while you are on the site. Try logging in to the front end and logging out again if you just added the guest group option.

Comment: Thanks David - that did the trick, I wonder what causes it not to update.  Do you know which table the updates are put into?

Comment: When you first visit the site, it should make a session variable for the user. This is what keeps you logged in as you move around the site. As far as I can tell, it just loads the user's group on creating the session variable, so you either have to wait for the session to die (typically an hour I believe) or login/logout to create a new session variable. There is a session table that you could clear as well that may do the trick, but it is also partly on the PHP side. Either way, you should be good moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is an answer.  Logging out, clear the cache (press f5) and then logging in fixed the issue.  Hours spent tracking it down.